# ftp issue with team member in India

Tags: linux, firewall, ftp, sftp, ubuntu-14.04

Running nginx and a fairly normal lemp stack i'm trying to allow a colleague to connect from his house.

I've allowed access to his IP inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

I've tested his credentials using a standard ftp client (filezilla) and it logs me into the server no problem. When he trys to run it on his end it just keeps timing out. We are running sftp with a normal username and password on our website.

No port is necessary on my end. Any ideas?  when i `tail -f nginx.error.log`.. i get this `2018/01/30 20:12:42 [error] 10051#0: *70 access forbidden by rule.`

maybe i have to edit the firewall too?

Comment: is the connection on your end going thru a router? if so have you forwarded port 22 via the router?  (Port 22 is used by sftp on a local connection it's assumed, if your box has a router between it and the internet, then port forwarding on the router must be enabled for port 22)

Comment: @Tyson my connection is going through a netgear router / cable modem combo, correct. It works fine on my filezilla when i connect sftp to the remote server using port 22 or not using port 22. I'll ask my partner if he's going through a router.. he is the one having issues.

Comment: The client end doesn't matter, outbound ports are opened on demand.  On the server end the Inbound port must be forwarded at the router.

Comment: @Tyson The access is controlled by IP address, i believe. If the address keeps a static IP (for one user) address it should work fine. If it does not, then it will only work 1 time. << i believe this is the problem because I used it first to test and it's assigned to my ip? Would that make sense, or no? If so how can i fix this issue...

Comment: Are you sure you've allowed access to his public IP?  If so, then let him try passive ftp.

Comment: What does passive ftp do? I'll have him try that later. @GerardH.Pille

Comment: It does ftp, what else?  But since routers are involved and probably firewalls, please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699145/what-is-the-difference-between-active-and-passive-ftp#1699163

Comment: How is nginx concerned in this?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Nginx is where i whitelist various ips for various things.

Comment: If one of this various things is FTP, are you sure nginx can handle that?  There are people saying it can't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472363/how-to-reroute-sftp-traffic-via-nginx